# Is there any External data REST API available for Salesforce Wave Analytics?

Tags: rest-api, einstein-analytics

I want to upload external data csv file to create a dataset in Salesforce Wave Analytics using External Data API but i cannot find any useful **REST API** for same. Can someone provide me links?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Docs only show via partner WSDL .You can easily translate it to a REST API version .

Here are the steps you will need to do in REST API

1.Oauth and obtain access Token from Salesforce Instance

2.Create a row in InsightsExternalData object using rest api by making a http post request to below url

```
/services/data/v39.0/sobjects/InsightsExternalData
```

The object structure is as below

```
{
 "Format": "Csv",
 "EdgemartAlias": "Test",
 "Operation": "Overwrite",
  "Action": "none",
  "MetadataJson" :base64encodeofmetaJSON
}
```

> Kindly note if you have metadata.json then convert into base64 encoded format and add an additional field in the object as metadata

3.Note the Id from previous step and make a POST request to the below url

`/services/data/v39.0/sobjects/InsightsExternalDataPart` with below JSON

```
[{
    "DataFile": base64data,
    "InsightsExternalDataId": parentId,
    "PartNumber": 1
},
{
    "DataFile": base64data,
    "InsightsExternalDataId": parentId,
    "PartNumber": 2
},

{
    "DataFile": base64data,
    "InsightsExternalDataId": parentId,
    "PartNumber": 3
},

{
    "DataFile": base64data,
    "InsightsExternalDataId": parentId,
    "PartNumber": 4
  }
]
```

> Note parentId is obtained from Step 2

4.Initiate the upload by updating the InsightsExternalData .Make a PATCH with below JSON

`/services/data/v39.0/sobjects/InsightsExternalData/parentId`

```
{
    "Action": "Process",
    "parentId": parentId
}
```

Note ParentId is obtained from step 2

Comment: Is there any documentation available on this?

Comment: @user44769 The docs show partner WSDL and all i did was use salesforce REST API doc and convert equivalent of it .https://developer.salesforce.com/page/REST_API .You can use https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php to test .Thanks

Comment: I tried your way to use external data API, but in step 3 when i am trying to make a POST call using below data:
{
    "DataFile": "base64data",
    "InsightsExternalDataId": "06V7F000000L0OdUAK",
    "PartNumber": 1,
    "metadata":"base64data"
}
i am getting an error as:
[
  {
    "message": "No such column 'metadata' on sobject of type InsightsExternalDataPart",
    "errorCode": "INVALID_FIELD"
  }
]

Comment: So i realized rest does not do mass .Can you try with individual records in step 3 and not whole array

Comment: Could you please revisit my previous comment? It was incomplete earlier.

and Yes i've tried providing individual record.

Comment: No metadata column needed for third step .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58461/discussion-between-user44769-and-mohith-shrivastava).

Comment: Is there any specific reason why this process is not documented in any of official salesforce documentation?