# Is there any way to retrieve metadata file for a dataset through REST API in Salesforce Wave Analytics?

Tags: rest-api, einstein-analytics

I have created a dataset in Wave Analytics through REST External data API. How can i retrieve the metadata files used for creating that dataset using **JUST NAME OR ID OR OTHER COMMONLY AVAILABLE DETAILS** of dataset?

The 2 ways that i am aware of to retrieve metadata.json file for a dataset are:

**1. Using GET API /InsightsExternalData/ID:**

I cannot use this way because InsightsExternalData id cannot be stored. As far as i know it is temporary which gets created everytime.

**2. Using https://ap5.salesforce.com/insights/internal_api/v1.0/esObject/edgemart/dataset_id/version/version_id/file/main.xmd.json**

I cannot use this way either because the response from this API doesn't gives me exact information that i use to create the metadata file for that dataset.

Comment: can you please share the steps to create dataset through rest API?

Comment: @ Amal You can find the steps here- https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/173525/is-there-any-external-data-rest-api-available-for-salesforce-wave-analytics. Although there are some changes that are required for REST approach which are discussed in comments section. You can find API documentation here- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_ext_data.meta/bi_dev_guide_ext_data/bi_ext_data_object_externaldata.htm

Answer (score 1):

method:GET

https:///services/data/v39.0/sobjects/InsightsExternalData//MetadataJson

parentID - ID after uploading the InsightExternalData header object